# JLabel text alignment

Tags: java, jlabel

I need to change the label alignment from the default to the other way.
Tried to do that but it didn't work

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(text, SwingConstants.RIGHT);
label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
```

But the text stayed the same.

Comment: This should work.Maybe your `JLabel` uses the whole width of its container. Then you cant see the difference.

Comment: Tried it before but I didn't increase it enough, just did it again and it worked. Thanks!